# sec_error_untrusted_issuer with new certificate from CACert.org

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, firefox

I have a server certificate from CACert.org since two years. I have added CACert's root certificate to my browser. Everything worked fine, until my certificate expired. So I renewed my certificate on CACert.org and updated my .crt file on the server. But now I get sec_error_untrusted_issuer on the browser. But why? The issuer didn't change.

Answer (score 1):

Did they change the intermediate certificate linking them to the root certificate, so that they can all bind together?

http://www.cacert.org/index.php?id=3 is showing they have a 2005 start date on the intermediate cert, which will need to be bound into your server key stream.